# How do I work with the Qt data base in Python?

Tags: python, database, qt, pyqt, qtsql

I'm beginning with PyQt and heard that the Qt comes with a special data base module named QtSQL. The docs of the module, like everything in Qt, cover only C++ usage. In my work, I'll need a data base which can be accessed by more than one software by the time (local network). I would like to know if someone works with the QtSQL and could give some tips of how to learn more about it. Is it possible to work with it in local network? Is it ready-to-use when the PyQt4 is installed or do I need to install something more? And what about the license?

Comment: you can try SqlAlchemy . It's an ORM . But it's a separate package . I use it extensively and you can connect most of the databases with it. Easy to learn .Take a look at it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `PyQt` [supports](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) `QtSql`. Note that it's not a database in itself, but rather a unified interface to database libraries:

> The QtSql module contains classes that
>   integrate with open-source and
>   proprietary SQL databases. It includes
>   editable data models for database
>   tables that can be used with GUI
>   classes. It also includes an
>   implementation of SQLite.

So you should tie it in to an existing database such as MySql. Note that Python also has its own APIs for databases available, so you'll have a choice here.

The license for `PyQt` is GPL.

As for how to learn more about it, I would suggest to first learn about databases in general and try to understand your requirements and what DB you need to fulfill them. Once you understand that, picking the Python DB binding should be easy.

Comment: I didn't realize that QtSQL was just a sort of API for DB. Then it's really not what I'm looking for in my project. Thank you very much for the precise answer.